# Kotlin PWA Android, getInstalledRelatedApps not working

Tags: android, kotlin, progressive-web-apps

I have made a (almost) clone app of an old app made with Java, but now with Kotlin.

It's a pwa, it just shows a webview with an URL.

My problem is that in the web, I have a code that check tif the app is installed:

```
if ('getInstalledRelatedApps' in navigator) {
  const relatedApps = await navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps();
```

But navigator comes empty, but with the old app in JAVA comes with all the data and the code above of the page works.

Is there another way to check if the app is installed but not using getInstalledRelatedApps with a Kotlin PWA?